# Can add 'customers-list' to 'customers' module

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular and I'm running in the following error when I try to add '' to my customers.component.html:

> 1. If 'app-customers-list' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'app-customers-list' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>      [...]

I now this is a very common error, but I can't seem to find what I'm missing. It appears I am not correctly importing my customer-list compoent to my customers.module.

Here are my files:

- customers.module.ts:

  ```
  import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
  import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

  import { CustomersComponent }  from './customers.component';
  import { CustomersListComponent } from './customers-list/customers-list.component';

  @NgModule({
  imports:      [ CommonModule ],
  declarations: [ CustomersComponent, CustomersListComponent ],
  exports: [ CustomersComponent,CustomersListComponent ]

   })
   export class CustomersModule { }
  ```
- customer.list.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-customers-list',
  templateUrl: './customers-list.component.html'

})
export class CustomersListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: Try adding `CustomersListComponent` to the `exports` array in the module, just like you're doing with `CustomersComponent`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but that didn't work, still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You should import you component in your `app.module.ts` not in `customers.module.ts`.

app.module.ts

```
// MODULES

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ngModule } from '@angular/core';
...

// COMPONENTS

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CustomersComponent }  from './customers/customers.component';
import { CustomersListComponent } from './customers/customers-list/customers-list.component';
...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
    CustomersComponent,
    CustomersListComponent
    ...
  ]
})
```

Comment: I wanted to 'customers-list' to be a child of my 'customers' component

Comment: Yes I saw that but for what purpose exactly do you want to add an other module file ? You don't need to add module file for child system: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: My customers module is supposedly a big part of my project, hence its module status.